# how to properly seal emitter cap

Tags: plumbing, french-drain

I have an emitter pipe in my front yard and when it rains the cap blows off completely, instead of just opening up its top.

[image: Cap]

I tried some white PVC plumbers glue, but it failed to hold after a few weeks. How can I properly keep this cap on my drain pipe so it doesn't get blasted off by the water?

Comment: What plastic is it made out of, should be stamped or a label on it?  Need to use glue made for the plastic and the joints need to be cleaned of all other stuff.  Picture looks like it might have clips, so a large hose clamp might help tighten it.  Have you checked that the cap opens easy or does it require some force?

Comment: The inner cap opens very easily but I think the pressure is so great that it pushed out the entire thing comes off.  Not sure about the type of plastic.

Comment: Is there a retainer for the cap that's supposed to hold it in place while letting water out? Is said retainer broken off? Maybe pics of your actual emitter (inside of pipe & inside of cap) instead of a generic image from the internet will help us solve your problem instead of a generic internet problem.

Comment: No retainer. I found the one I have here. In a video, this guy says "simply slide the cap into place": https://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-Pop-Up-Drainage-Emitter-for-3-in-4-in-Drain-Fittings-Green-Plastic-420C/202959185#overlay

Comment: Maybe you need a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just putting a screw through each side of the pipe to hold the emitter in place. It's worked for two weeks now and seems solid.